# Permission called twice when we have mutableStateOf in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have following permission check in Jetpack Compose :

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { permissions ->
    if (permissions.values.first { true }) {
        log.info("Permission is granted")
        shouldDisplayQuestionDialog.value = true
    } else {
        log.info("Permission is not granted")
    }
}
```

When I deny permission, **Permission is not granted** log called once.

Now I change the code to this :

```
val displayEmptyScreen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { permissions ->
    if (permissions.values.first { true }) {
        log.info("Permission is granted")
        shouldDisplayQuestionDialog.value = true
    } else {
        log.info("Permission is not granted")
        displayEmptyScreen.value = true
    }
}
```

Now **Permission is not granted** log called twice after adding the `mutableStateOf`. Why is that? How to make it call once?

**ADDENDA**

```
@Composable
    private fun DisplayPermissionDialog(shouldDisplayQuestionDialog: MutableState<Boolean>) {
        val displayEmptyScreen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) { permissions ->
            if (permissions.values.first { true }) {
                log.info("Permission is granted")
                shouldDisplayQuestionDialog.value = true
            } else {
                log.info("Permission is not granted")
                displayEmptyScreen.value = true
            }
        }
        DisplayQuestionAlertDialog(shouldDisplayQuestionDialog)
        if (displayEmptyScreen.value) {
            Box {
                // This box works as background
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .matchParentSize()
                        .background(Color.White)
                )
            }
        }
        val context = LocalContext.current
        when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) -> {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    log.info("Set State for mutableStateFlow")
                    viewModel.setState()
                }
                DisplayQuestionAlertDialog(shouldDisplayQuestionDialog)
            }
            else -> {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    // Asking for permission
                    launcher.launch(
                        arrayOf(
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Presumably, something is observing `displayEmptyScreen`, and when you change the value, it is causing recomposition. If you are calling `launch()` on each recomposition, that would explain the behavior. Your `launch()` may need to be wrapped in some sort of effect to better control recomposition behavior. Or, reorganize your composables such that the observer of `displayEmptyScreen` does not trigger a new `launch()` call on recomposition.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the whole method to the end of question. Can you help me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code guarantees that `DisplayPermissionDialog()` will be called at least twice, if you do not hold the permission at the time that you called `DisplayPermissionDialog()` initially.

The first time through, if you do not hold permission, you will go into the `else` branch of your `when()`, and you will use your `launcher` to bring up a system permission dialog. That will eventually trigger your lambda on `launcher`, which mutates state whether you were granted permission or not.

Since `DisplayPermissionDialog()` reads that same state, `DisplayPermissionDialog()` will be called a second time (the function is "recomposed"). And, on that second time through if you do not hold permission, you will go into the `else` branch of your `when()`, and you will use your `launcher` to bring up a system permission dialog. That will eventually trigger your lambda on `launcher`, which mutates state whether you were granted permission or not.

Frankly, I would expect an infinite chain of recompositions once you get to the point where Android stops showing the system permission dialog.

Either:

- Do not mutate state that this function reads when the user rejects your permission request, or
- Arrange it such that you do not call `launch()` on your `launcher` on every call of this function when you do not hold permission

I cannot give you more specific advice, just because this is not my function and I do not fully understand what you're trying to do here.

For more, you might want to watch [this screencast on runtime permissions in Compose UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UujnB__Lek). Or, try [Accompanist's permission composables](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/) — see [this Medium post](https://medium.com/compose-in-the-room/requesting-permissions-with-ease-in-jetpack-compose-using-accompanist-permissions-apis-76d5d9ca5f97) for more on that library.